# Proof: If a vector space V is generated by a finite set S, then some subset of S is a basis for V.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

The proof in the textbook linear algebra 4th edition by Stephen H. Friedberg Arnold J. Insel Lawrence E. Spence

> [image: theorem]

In the last part:
" Let v $\in$  S. If v $\in$  $\beta$, then clearly v $\in$  span($\beta$). Otherwise, if v $\notin$ $\beta$, then the preceding
construction shows that $\beta$ $\cup$ {v} is linearly dependent. So v $\in$  span($\beta$) by
Theorem 1.7 (p. 39). Thus S $\subseteq$ span($\beta$)"

＂$\beta$ $\cup$ {v} is linearly dependent" is also correct when v $\in$ V-$\beta$ besides v $\in$  S-$\beta$, right?

So can we say it alternatively :
Let v $\in$  "V". If v $\in$  $\beta$, then clearly v $\in$  span($\beta$). Otherwise, if v $\notin$ $\beta$, then the preceding
construction shows that $\beta$ $\cup$ {v} is linearly dependent. So v $\in$ span($\beta$) by Theorem 1.7 (p. 39). Thus "V" $\subseteq$ span($\beta$)."?

Is this correct?

Comment: Please use MathJax to do mathematical mark-up. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/742).

Comment: The priori assumed in the theorem is that $S$ is a generating set for $V$, so once you show that $S$ is generated by $\beta$, it is clear that $\beta$ generates the entire space $V$ since $\operatorname{span}(\beta)\supseteq\operatorname{span}(S)=V$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not correct. The “preceding construction” only shows that if you add an element $v$ of $S$ to $\beta$, then the set $\beta\cup\{v\}$ is linearly dependent (since $\beta$ is a maximal linearly independent subset of $S$). But the construction of $S$ doesn't allow you to deduce directly that $\beta\cup\{v\}$ is linearly dependent for an arbitrary element of $V$.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood the preceding construction's range that is only limited in S.